Let $V$ be the vector space of $3\times3$ matrices with rank $2$, what will be the dimension of $V$?
Let $V$ be the vector space of $3\times3$ matrices with rank $2$, what will be the dimension of $V$?
I don't know how to find the dimension of this type of vector space where rank of an element (matrix) is given, please help me to solve this. What is the relation between the rank and dimension here?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is not a vector space... Take $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)$ and $B=\operatorname{diag}(0,1,1)$ then $A+B$ has rank $3$.

It is an eight-dimensional manifold with equation det(A)=0, bounded by the five-dimensional set of matrices with rank 1

I think the dimension of the set of $N\times N$ matrices of rank $R$ is $N^2-(N-R)^2$.  Speaking roughly, the first $R$ rows can be anything,  Using row operations, the $R$ pivots can set $R$ of the entries in the remaining rows to zero, but the original matrix is only rank $R$ if the remaining $N-R$ entries of the remaining $N-R$ vectors are then zero.

$V$ can not be a vector space. One property any vector space has is that any two elements added are still in the vector space. Can you think of a counter example?

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
